# returning the max value from Sqlite DB

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a SQLite database and I am tyring to query the max value in the RecordID field. This query works when I run it in SQLite but I can not get the VB to return the value, what have I done wrong?

```
Dim getMaxRecID As String = "SELECT MAX(RecordID) FROM String"
Using cmd1 As New SQLiteCommand(getMaxRecID, pConn)
      cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
      Dim IDresults As Integer

      Try
          IDresults = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Catch ex As Exception

          Throw
      End Try
```

The connection is correctly opening the db, and shows it as open as well. No error, just IDresults returns 0 everytime.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it....

```
                    Dim ds2 As New DataSet
                    Dim da2 As SQLiteDataAdapter

                    Try
                        da2 = New SQLiteDataAdapter(getMaxRecID, pConn)
                        da2.Fill(ds2)

                        IDresults = ds2.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
```